# react request error catching

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am trying to catch errors in my http response. I am using React-redux as frontend. So first of all I have a simple request handling, where I check status of every request and according to status code I return response or throw error:

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }

  return parseJSON(response).then(responseFormatted => {
    const error = new Error(response.error);
    error.response = response;
    error.response.payload = responseFormatted;
    throw error;
  });
}
```

I aspect that my error will be `response.error` from response's body json. My body looks like:

```
{
    error:"Bad Request",
    message:"Validation failed for object='loginRequest'. Error count: 2",
    status:400,
    timestamp:"2029-02-03T08:58:34.838+0000"
}
```

Later in my redux-saga I try to catch this error:

```
export function* func() {
  try {
    let requestURL = "some url";

    const response = yield call(request, requestURL, { method: 'POST', body });

    if (response.accessToken) {
        'Authenticate'
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

And it returns error to my console, that :

```
Error at eval line const error = new Error(response.error);
```

Maybe someone could tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch (native and polyfill) and libraries such Axios have a catch feature already managed without need of error code managing, IE:

```js
// Example with AXIOS
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });

// Example with FETCH
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    return response.blob();
  }
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(myBlob) { 
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob); 
  myImage.src = objectURL; 
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to customize my requests, that's why I want to write my own requests handling.